# React-Native Flat List cannot list individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In my FlatList, I want to map the incoming data (outputData.output) with separate style and the input (formData) with separate style.

I have 3 states.

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState();
  const [outputData, setOutputData] = useState();

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

formData is coming from my input. I am sending it to API, outputData is returning back from my API. I combined them all under "messages" state.

What I want is to style the data coming from the formData separately and the data from outputData separately.

Like so:

[image]

My code is:

```
<FlatList
          data={[{ key: messages }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            if (item) {
              return <Text style={styles.currentMember}>{item.key}</Text>;
            } else if (item.key.output) {
              return <Text style={styles.message}>{item}</Text>;
            }
          }}
        />
```

But it is not working.

Messages array:

```
Array [
  "Hi! How can I help you?",
  "Hi",
  "Test",
  "Yep test 2",
]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha I am making a chat app. My messages should be in a different style, incoming messages should be in a different style. I could not set this up.

Comment: How about you keep them in the same array and define a property in each object to identify which one is which. According to that you can conditionally change style. I don't know what your code structure is, but it could be a solution may be ?

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha They are in same array already called `messages`. But how can I define a property in each object to identify?

Comment: Can you show me your messages Array?

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha I edited my code. It's just an array.

Comment: So you are storing just strings in that array. Push objects in that array instead of strings like [{type: input, text: 'Hi, How can I help you?'},{type: output,text:'Hi'}]

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha It gives `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, text}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.]`.

Comment: Can you just make a codesandbox link so I can look into the code ?